# VBA code to download data from website under some condition

Tags: vba

I need to download gold price from this website https://eximbank.com.vn/home/Static/Gold.aspx under 2 condition (date and table number)as below. This code debug with run time error 438 "Object doesn't support this property or method" when I choose date and table number. Could anyone tell me why it is. Many thanks in advance!

```
  Sub Eximbank()
  Dim myIE As New InternetExplorer
  Dim myIEDoc As HTMLDocument
  myIE.Visible = False
  myIE.navigate "https://eximbank.com.vn/home/Static/Gold.aspx"
  Do While myIE.readyState <> 4 Or myIE.Busy
  DoEvents
  Loop
  Set myIEDoc = myIE.document

   ' Choose Date and Table number
  myIEDoc.getElementsByName("CalControl1$TextBox1").Value = "14/04/2020"
  myIEDoc.getElementsByName("ddlQuoteCount").Value = "19"
  myIEDoc.getElementsByName("ImageButton1").Click

 'Download data to active workbook
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") = Now
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")=myIEDoc.getElementsById("GoldRateRepeater_lblCSHBUYRT_0")(0).getElementsByTagName("td")(0).innerText
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1") = myIEDoc.getElementsById("GoldRateRepeater_lblCSHSELLRT_0")(0).getElementsByTagName("td")(1).innerText

 myIE.Quit
Set myIE = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: `getElementsById` >> `getElementById` and you do not use `(0)` with that.  But you do need `(0)` with `getElementsByName` since that returns a collection not a single element.  You also need to wait for the page to refresh between clicking the button and getting the data.

Comment: Will it always be the day before current day that you want? Also, some of your elements are inside an iframe and your initial date selection involves a POST request that you need to ensure it fired. You could try mimicking the full set of GET/POST requests this aspx page makes but that is definitely more fiddly.

Comment: Hi Tim Williams! I changed these code as you suggested but it still debug with run time error 91- Object variable or With block variable not set at this command myIEDoc.getElementsByName("CalControl1$TextBox1")(0).Value = "14/04/2020". Besides, I skip date and table number option to download current data to active workbook after changing getElementsById >> getElementById. It still returned the same run time error.

Comment: Hi QHarr! I need to download data daily, not just some specific days. I also changed some command as Tim Williams suggested but it didn't run properly. Could you give me some ideas about it?